# How to set variable for two views via UI of react app?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app, in different routes render different components

```
--App
 |-view1
    |-child component1_1
    |-child component1_2
 |-view2
    |-child component2_1
    |-child component2_2
 |-Toggle
```

in main view there's a toggle and i want to set is as:

If enabled, then some children of the two paths (). All actions in my application will use API_URL_1, else, use API_URL_2.

App.js:

```
render(){
    return(
         .... 
         <Route path="/path_1" component={Component1}>
         <Route path="/path_2" component={Component2}>
         .....
         <Toggle onChange={this.changeToggle()} />
    )
}
```

React Context is a way, but I feel it's too complicated for just one global variable. Is there an more simple way?

The state of Toggle is kept in app, so I want to pass the status of this Toggle to some children of path1 and some children of path2.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by view?

Comment: Your intention is a little bit unclear with this little code. With children, do you mean `view1` and `view2` component's children? (By the way, start your components names with a capital letter). Please share us other parts of your component. Where do you keep this `toggle` value? In the state?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. just modified a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Global app state spread over multiple components on different levels of nesting can be provided via context. This is a valid use case.

Another probably better solution is to not give the components a url in the first place. You could have a dedicated service module doing api requests that exposes a function to toggle the two endpoints. It keeps track of the currently used endpoint.

This way the components do not need to know about the endpoints itself. They just import the service and call functions on it to 1. make requests and 2. toggle the endpoints.

This does not pollute the global namespace because the currently used url is local to the service module and can't be directly mutated.